# Quitar etiquetas html al hacer binding en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

Tengo un json el cual contiene texto con etiquetas html. Quisiera saber como quitar dichas etiquetas he estado revisando que ng-bind-html ayuda, pero la verdad no se como implementarlo. Espero me puedan ayudar.

A continuación comparto mis archivos

Json (el dato que quiero mostrar es contenido):

```
[
  {
    "responsable": "SISTEMAS INFORMÁTICOS Y COMPUTACIÓN",
    "tipo": "TITULACION",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "modalidad": "PRESENCIAL",
    "componente": {
      "nombre": "METODOLOGIAS AGILES",
      "guid": "2d25d627-6440-0050-e053-ac10360dd136",
      "codigo": "PRE-TNCCO210",
      "subcomponente": {},
      "paralelo": {
        "nombre": "A",
        "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b6-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
        "horario": {
          "docente": {
            "guid": "a7c2dd51-1865-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
            "identificacion": "0921250601001",
            "nombre": "FERNANDA MARICELA SOTO GUERRERO"
          },
          "registro": {
            "id": 1094,
            "estado": "VALIDADO",
            "contenido": "\u003cp\u003eTema 1.  Fundamentos de las metodologías ágiles\u003cbr /\u003e1.1. Modelos de proceso de desarrollo software\u003cbr /\u003e1.2. El Movimiento ágil\u003cbr /\u003e1.3. Metodologías ágiles de desarrollo\u003cbr /\u003e1.4. Metodologías ágiles versus tradicionales\u003c/p\u003e/nForma de evaluación y características de la materia.",
            "id_contenido_plan": 80989,
            "fecha_clase": "05-04-2016"
          },
          "tipo": "CLASE",
          "parte": "TEORÍA",
          "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b2-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
          "dia": "MARTES",
          "aula": "226",
          "hora_inicio": "07:30:00",
          "hora_fin": "10:00:00"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "responsable": "SISTEMAS INFORMÁTICOS Y COMPUTACIÓN",
    "tipo": "TITULACION",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "modalidad": "PRESENCIAL",
    "componente": {
      "nombre": "METODOLOGIAS AGILES",
      "guid": "2d25d627-6440-0050-e053-ac10360dd136",
      "codigo": "PRE-TNCCO210",
      "subcomponente": {},
      "paralelo": {
        "nombre": "A",
        "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b6-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
        "horario": {
          "docente": {
            "guid": "a7c2dd51-1865-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
            "identificacion": "0921250601001",
            "nombre": "FERNANDA MARICELA SOTO GUERRERO"
          },
          "registro": {
            "id": 1095,
            "estado": "VALIDADO",
            "contenido": "\u003cp\u003eTema 1.  Fundamentos de las metodologías ágiles\u003cbr /\u003e1.1. Modelos de proceso de desarrollo software\u003cbr /\u003e1.2. El Movimiento ágil\u003cbr /\u003e1.3. Metodologías ágiles de desarrollo\u003cbr /\u003e1.4. Metodologías ágiles versus tradicionales\u003c/p\u003e",
            "id_contenido_plan": 80989,
            "fecha_clase": "12-04-2016"
          },
          "tipo": "CLASE",
          "parte": "TEORÍA",
          "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b2-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
          "dia": "MARTES",
          "aula": "226",
          "hora_inicio": "07:30:00",
          "hora_fin": "10:00:00"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Controller
    MostrarRegistros.servicioMostrarRegistros($rootScope.idCe).success(function(data){
          $scope.datosTuto=data;
          $scope.cont=$scope.datosTuto.length;// contador que muestra el # de registros creados 
        })

Vista.html

```
<ion-item class="item item-avatar-center" type="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="i in datosTuto | filter:busqueda" 
                href="#/Gtuto/componentes/{{Nom_coe}}/EdicionTutorias/{{i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.id}}">
        <h2>{{i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.contenido}}</h2>
        <h6>{{i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.id}}</h6>
        <!--Esto es para borrar un item-->
        <ion-delete-button class="ion-trash-a" ng-click="onItemDelete(i)"></ion-delete-button>
      </ion-item>
```

Al mostrar contenido en mi app muestra las etiquetas p,br,entre otras

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres es simple. Incluye `angular-sanitize.js` en tu código y especifica el módulo `ngSanitize` como dependencia.

Si estás usando `ionic.bundle.js` ya no necesitas incluir el fichero ya que este es una concatenación de `ionic.js`, `angular.js`, `angular-animate.js`, `angular-sanitize.js`, `angular-ui-router.js` y `ionic-angular.js`.

Por ultimo sólo tienes que poner la directiva [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) para hacerle binding a la parte que quieres mostrar como html. Lo que esto hará es procesar tu input usando el servicio [$sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize). Si el html que manejas es tan simple como en el ejemplo que pones no habrá problemas.

Aquí te dejo un demo

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize', 'ionic'])
  .controller('DatosCtrl', function($scope, sampleData) {
    $scope.datosTuto = sampleData;
  })
  .factory('sampleData', function() {
    return [{
      "responsable": "SISTEMAS INFORMÁTICOS Y COMPUTACIÓN",
      "tipo": "TITULACION",
      "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
      "nivel": "PREGRADO",
      "modalidad": "PRESENCIAL",
      "componente": {
        "nombre": "METODOLOGIAS AGILES",
        "guid": "2d25d627-6440-0050-e053-ac10360dd136",
        "codigo": "PRE-TNCCO210",
        "subcomponente": {},
        "paralelo": {
          "nombre": "A",
          "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b6-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
          "horario": {
            "docente": {
              "guid": "a7c2dd51-1865-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
              "identificacion": "0921250601001",
              "nombre": "FERNANDA MARICELA SOTO GUERRERO"
            },
            "registro": {
              "id": 1094,
              "estado": "VALIDADO",
              "contenido": "\u003cp\u003eTema 1.  Fundamentos de las metodologías ágiles\u003cbr /\u003e1.1. Modelos de proceso de desarrollo software\u003cbr /\u003e1.2. El Movimiento ágil\u003cbr /\u003e1.3. Metodologías ágiles de desarrollo\u003cbr /\u003e1.4. Metodologías ágiles versus tradicionales\u003c/p\u003e/nForma de evaluación y características de la materia.",
              "id_contenido_plan": 80989,
              "fecha_clase": "05-04-2016"
            },
            "tipo": "CLASE",
            "parte": "TEORÍA",
            "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b2-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
            "dia": "MARTES",
            "aula": "226",
            "hora_inicio": "07:30:00",
            "hora_fin": "10:00:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }, {
      "responsable": "SISTEMAS INFORMÁTICOS Y COMPUTACIÓN",
      "tipo": "TITULACION",
      "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
      "nivel": "PREGRADO",
      "modalidad": "PRESENCIAL",
      "componente": {
        "nombre": "METODOLOGIAS AGILES",
        "guid": "2d25d627-6440-0050-e053-ac10360dd136",
        "codigo": "PRE-TNCCO210",
        "subcomponente": {},
        "paralelo": {
          "nombre": "A",
          "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b6-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
          "horario": {
            "docente": {
              "guid": "a7c2dd51-1865-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
              "identificacion": "0921250601001",
              "nombre": "FERNANDA MARICELA SOTO GUERRERO"
            },
            "registro": {
              "id": 1095,
              "estado": "VALIDADO",
              "contenido": "\u003cp\u003eTema 1.  Fundamentos de las metodologías ágiles\u003cbr /\u003e1.1. Modelos de proceso de desarrollo software\u003cbr /\u003e1.2. El Movimiento ágil\u003cbr /\u003e1.3. Metodologías ágiles de desarrollo\u003cbr /\u003e1.4. Metodologías ágiles versus tradicionales\u003c/p\u003e",
              "id_contenido_plan": 80989,
              "fecha_clase": "12-04-2016"
            },
            "tipo": "CLASE",
            "parte": "TEORÍA",
            "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b2-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
            "dia": "MARTES",
            "aula": "226",
            "hora_inicio": "07:30:00",
            "hora_fin": "10:00:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DatosCtrl">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item item-avatar-center" type="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="i in datosTuto | filter:busqueda" href="#/Gtuto/componentes/{{Nom_coe}}/EdicionTutorias/{{i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.id}}">
      <h2 ng-bind-html="i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.contenido"></h2>
      <h6>{{i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.id}}</h6>
      <!--Esto es para borrar un item-->
      <ion-delete-button class="ion-trash-a" ng-click="onItemDelete(i)"></ion-delete-button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

Ahora si el html que estás manejando es algo más complicado que eso y te da problemas deberías usar el servicio [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) y llamar al método `trustAsHtml` siempre y cuando confíes en el contenido de lo que estas intentando mostrar. Cuando digo "confíes" me refiero a que no sea input del usuario o que al menos controles como este se inserta ya que puede ser un vector para inyección de código.

Este es el demo en caso que tengas que usar el servicio $sce

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize', 'ionic'])
  .controller('DatosCtrl', function($scope, sampleData, $sce) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sampleData.length; i++) {
      $sce.trustAsHtml(sampleData[i].componente.paralelo.horario.registro.contenido);
    }
    $scope.datosTuto = sampleData;
  })
  .factory('sampleData', function() {
    return [{
      "responsable": "SISTEMAS INFORMÁTICOS Y COMPUTACIÓN",
      "tipo": "TITULACION",
      "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
      "nivel": "PREGRADO",
      "modalidad": "PRESENCIAL",
      "componente": {
        "nombre": "METODOLOGIAS AGILES",
        "guid": "2d25d627-6440-0050-e053-ac10360dd136",
        "codigo": "PRE-TNCCO210",
        "subcomponente": {},
        "paralelo": {
          "nombre": "A",
          "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b6-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
          "horario": {
            "docente": {
              "guid": "a7c2dd51-1865-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
              "identificacion": "0921250601001",
              "nombre": "FERNANDA MARICELA SOTO GUERRERO"
            },
            "registro": {
              "id": 1094,
              "estado": "VALIDADO",
              "contenido": "\u003cp\u003eTema 1.  Fundamentos de las metodologías ágiles\u003cbr /\u003e1.1. Modelos de proceso de desarrollo software\u003cbr /\u003e1.2. El Movimiento ágil\u003cbr /\u003e1.3. Metodologías ágiles de desarrollo\u003cbr /\u003e1.4. Metodologías ágiles versus tradicionales\u003c/p\u003e/nForma de evaluación y características de la materia.",
              "id_contenido_plan": 80989,
              "fecha_clase": "05-04-2016"
            },
            "tipo": "CLASE",
            "parte": "TEORÍA",
            "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b2-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
            "dia": "MARTES",
            "aula": "226",
            "hora_inicio": "07:30:00",
            "hora_fin": "10:00:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }, {
      "responsable": "SISTEMAS INFORMÁTICOS Y COMPUTACIÓN",
      "tipo": "TITULACION",
      "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
      "nivel": "PREGRADO",
      "modalidad": "PRESENCIAL",
      "componente": {
        "nombre": "METODOLOGIAS AGILES",
        "guid": "2d25d627-6440-0050-e053-ac10360dd136",
        "codigo": "PRE-TNCCO210",
        "subcomponente": {},
        "paralelo": {
          "nombre": "A",
          "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b6-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
          "horario": {
            "docente": {
              "guid": "a7c2dd51-1865-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
              "identificacion": "0921250601001",
              "nombre": "FERNANDA MARICELA SOTO GUERRERO"
            },
            "registro": {
              "id": 1095,
              "estado": "VALIDADO",
              "contenido": "\u003cp\u003eTema 1.  Fundamentos de las metodologías ágiles\u003cbr /\u003e1.1. Modelos de proceso de desarrollo software\u003cbr /\u003e1.2. El Movimiento ágil\u003cbr /\u003e1.3. Metodologías ágiles de desarrollo\u003cbr /\u003e1.4. Metodologías ágiles versus tradicionales\u003c/p\u003e",
              "id_contenido_plan": 80989,
              "fecha_clase": "12-04-2016"
            },
            "tipo": "CLASE",
            "parte": "TEORÍA",
            "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b2-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
            "dia": "MARTES",
            "aula": "226",
            "hora_inicio": "07:30:00",
            "hora_fin": "10:00:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DatosCtrl">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item item-avatar-center" type="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="i in datosTuto | filter:busqueda" href="#/Gtuto/componentes/{{Nom_coe}}/EdicionTutorias/{{i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.id}}">
      <h2 ng-bind-html="i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.contenido"></h2>
      <h6>{{i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.id}}</h6>
      <!--Esto es para borrar un item-->
      <ion-delete-button class="ion-trash-a" ng-click="onItemDelete(i)"></ion-delete-button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

Básicamente tienes mucho contenido html por lo que tienes que iterar y decirle a angular que confíe en cada una de esas entradas de html.

Comment: Gracias me ha servido mucho.. Excelente su ayuda